# Control the zoom level of Google Mx

Tags: javascript, jquery, maps

I've made a Wordpress website with a template tool 'beaver builder'. That tool has a google map module, but that doesn't work very well. For example, I can't change to zoom level and center.

I also want to show a specific marker in a cluster.

This is the website page: http://www.depot-rato.be/het-project/

Is there a way to control the google map with some Javascript or jQuery?

```
jQuery('.gmap').setZoom(19);
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I've found a solution:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) { 
    var aLocation = { lat: 51.009054, lng: 4.509285};

    $('.gmap').gmap('get','map').setOptions(
        {
            'zoom': 18,
            'center': aLocation
        }
    ); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I do it like this(at map initialization, resets the map and markers):

```
var aLocation= { lat: 48.4728146, lng: 7.499930100000029 };

map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('myMap'), {
    zoom: 5,
    center: aLocation,
    title: 'myMapTitle',
});
```

or like this(this one shouldn't initialize the map or markers):

```
map.setZoom(5);
map.setCenter(aLocation);

map.panTo(aLocation);// no need for this one, if you used the one above
```

You can try it here(click on the marker):

https://codepen.io/sam67/pen/KRGLjY

Comment: At the moment there are + 50 markers on the map. But when I use map = new google.maps.Map(......) it deletes all the markers.

And when I use map.setZoom(5) is throws an error: Uncaught ReferenceError: map is not defined

Comment: Is your 'var map' only in the init function? if so, try putting it as a global variable, so it can be defined outside of that function.(I changed my codepen)

Comment: I honestly don't know. Everything is initiated in the wordpress plugin. I can only add some Javascript to the website :( You can find the map over here: http://www.depot-rato.be/het-project/